# Microsoft Graph API: Get Files List API, giving Empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, office365, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-api

I tried API to fetch the files in iOS SDK.
I have registered app with all the scopes to read/readwrite files access to the app. I was able to send the mail using sample code successfully. 
I tried the APIs in Graph Explorer
https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net/?UrlRequest=GET&text=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fv1.0%2Fme%2Fdrive%2Froot%2Fchildren

Request snippet:

```
AuthenticationManager *authManager = [AuthenticationManager sharedInstance];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json, text/plain, */*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
NSString *authorization = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", authManager.accessToken];
[request setValue:authorization forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if(conn) {
    NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
}
[conn start];
```

Response:

```
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('<user-email>')/drive/root/children","value":[]}
```

Thanks in Advance for the help :)

Permissions for my sample app
[image: Permissions for my sample app]

Answer (score 1):

An empty response for that request is expected when the app doesn't have permission to access any files in the root directory of a given user's drive. Could you check (e.g. via http://jwt.calebb.net) if the access token that you're using has any Files.* scopes? Files.Read is sufficient for that request.

Comment: It is more over a comment rather than answr.

Comment: @Marek I have edited and added the permissions. SO everything is checked. Still getting the same response.

Comment: I assume that you do have some files or folders on your drive. If so could you provide response headers that got returned for one of your calls?

Comment: Could you try adding the 'Read items in all site collections' permission to your application?

Comment: @PavanSaberjack Please can you also clarify if you are accessing the signed in user's folder/files or another user's folder/files.