# Microsoft Graph API not returning Drive quota

Tags: azure, office365, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have the exact same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812693/microsoft-graph-api-get-files-list-api-giving-empty-array), however it looks like OP dropped off from troubleshooting.

I am accessing [this endpoint](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_get):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[UPN]/drive/
```

However the response is lacking the `quota` property (and an empty `owner` property):

```
{
  "@odata.context":
  "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives/$entity",
  "id": "[ID]",
  "driveType": "business",
  "owner": {
    "user": {}
  }
}
```

I can confirm via http://jwt.calebb.net/ that the `Files.Read.All` permission scope is applied to the application (in fact, I've ticked every box in the Azure app).

The token is being generated at the tenant level using the tenant's Account Object Id (ie, not on the user level).

Answer (score 0):

Based on some quick testing using the Microsoft Graph Explorer:
https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer

It appears to me that the result you are getting (with an empty owner property, and lacking quota) is a result of the fact that you do not have access to another person's drive information.

Specifically if we try the following query, using the Demo Tenant Available by the Graph Explorer:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive
```

I get all the data you are looking for. Even if I specifically call out the UPN of the demo user:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/alexd@a830edad9050849NDA1.onmicrosoft.com/drive
```

It works. However, if I try to query ANOTHER user:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/admin@a830edad9050849NDA1.onmicrosoft.com/drive
```

I get exactly what you posted above.
You should make sure that you are logged into the user account which you would like to query their Drive's quota information. I believe this will fix your issue.

EDIT:
I just noticed in your question that you mention you are getting an App Only Token. My guess is that this information is not available at the App Only Level, and again, requires a user to be signed in to get their specific drive information. I might need to follow up to understand if that is really a requirement here. But I hope you can, in the meantime, verify the fact that using a user token, you are able to resolve the drive information about that user.

Comment: Yep I can confirm that signing in with a user token I can return that user's drive information, however my requirements are for all users' quotas from an app level - delegated permissions will not be able to help me out here I'm afraid. The docs seem to suggest that this is possible at an app permission level

Comment: @Ian I am working through a similar problem. Did you manage to solve this issue without going the route of a single user sign on?

Comment: @jdave - no dice, I'm afraid. "Accessing other users drives will not return quota information" (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/645)

Comment: @Ian I reached out to the Microsoft Devs and this is what I got back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356174/microsoft-graph-csharp-sdk-and-onedrive-for-business-with-a-service-daemon-appli/42397387?noredirect=1#comment71944214_42397387