# Microsoft Graph CSharp SDK and OneDrive for Business with a Service/Daemon application - Quota facet returns null

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am coding against `Microsoft Graph CSharp SDK` for `OneDrive for Business` and I am trying to pull back data on a specific `User` and request back `Quota` information.

My request:

```
var user = await graphServiceClient.Users["test@test.onmicrosoft.com"].Request().GetAsync();
var drive = await graphServiceClient.Drives["test@test.onmicrosoft.com"].Request().GetAsync();
var quotaTotal = drive.Quota.Used;
var displayName = user.DisplayName;
var driveType = drive.DriveType;
var driveId = drive.Id;
```

The problem - the data that is returned is all `null`. Does the `Microsoft Graph SDK` have support to pull back `Quota` facet for `OneDrive for Bussiness` accounts?

*Update*

I am also providing the `client_id`, `client_secret`, and `tenant_name`to authenticate on an application-level permission.

**Update**

Added a screenshot for `drive` since it returns all null.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting the issue. The quota and owner information was indeed not being returned for App Only calls if you had Files.Read.All or Files.ReadWrite.All scope in the token. I have fixed the issue and the fix should roll out to Production soon.
As a workaround though, you can use Sites.FullControl.All scope for your app and that should return the quota and owner information.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an estimate on when this will go live?

Comment: No problem. It shouldn't take more than a couple of weeks.

Comment: This should now be fixed across Production. Please let me know if this is not the case.

Comment: This has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The quota.used facet is not being returned by the service (I'll report this issue). You can use the total and remaining properties to determine the amount of used quota.

**Update**
To answer your original question... Yes, the Microsoft Graph .Net Client library does support Quota and User on OneDrive for Business accounts.

I don't know why you aren't getting the quota returned in the response. I'm not familiar with OneDrive for Business quotas... Is it possible you don't have a quota? Just for the sake of being complete, I took your code:

```
var user = await graphClient.Users["user@test.onmicrosoft.com"].Request().GetAsync();
var drive = await graphClient.Drives["user@test.onmicrosoft.com"].Request().GetAsync();
var quotaTotal = drive.Quota.Used;
var displayName = user.DisplayName;
var driveType = drive.DriveType;
var driveId = drive.Id;
```

I successfully got back a **quota** object without the **used** property. Here's what I see in the response.

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives/$entity",
    "id": "<some ID>",
    "driveType": "business",
    "owner": {
        "user": {
            "id": "<some ID>",
            "displayName": "user"
        }
    },
    "quota": {
        "deleted": 4155859,
        "remaining": 1099484034353,
        "state": "normal",
        "total": 1099511627776
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question to include an image of the output. Everything for `Quota` and `User` are null on my calls.

Comment: what do you mean by sanitized response?

Comment: Also, when you were able to pull back user's **quota** data, was that due to the fact you logged in as a specific user? I am trying to access this data from an application level permissions. Since my authentication flow is that of a service /daemon application.

Comment: Yes, I was using a specific user. I wasn't trying this from a service application. That may be the potential source for what you're seeing. To address your other question, I was interested to see what the response body looked like so I could rule other potential causes. What I meant by sanitized response is that you'd remove any identifying or personal information like user ids and access tokens.